# Share Pc' s wifi internet connection to router and spit it out trough it

Tags: router, wireless-networking, internet-connection

Basicly im trying to share the an internet connection that i receive through wifi from my bestfriend's place to my place and Extend it trough a router for my consoles and other computers in my household

i have 1 pc with Wifi /Ethernet , one router "DD-wrt"ed"

Schema is like this

Internet ----->Modem-------> (Friend's)Router ----->to my  PC through Wifi (Ics)----> to Router(2) through lan-----> to Computer 1 (over lan or wifi etc...)
 ------> Computer 2 (over lan or wifi etc...)

i want the computer 1 and 2 to have internet from  Router(2)

if its not clear enough il try to give more details but a little help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to connect your computer to the router via the ethernet card and configure the system to transparently bridge the wifi card and the ethernet card.

This way every other computer connected to your router (working as a switch, not as a router) will see your friends router.

Note that you don't use the router WAN port for this.

Comment: how exactly do you "configure the system" ?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457038.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to plug your computer's network cable into the "WAN" socket on your router and just use Windows' Internet Connection Sharing.

This will mean, however, that your PC and the other machines connected to your router are on different networks and you will find it difficult to share stuff.

You could also try plugging your computer's network cable into one of the "LAN" sockets on your router as long as you turn off the DHCP server and NAT on your router. Now all connected devices should be on the same network.

Comment: I don't mind that the PC wont be able to share trough the router 2
All i care for is the internet.

i tried plugging in the pc ethernet cable into the Internet socket of my Wrt54g Linksys router and i disabled DHCP but yet couldnt surf the web on computer 1 while connected trough wifi to the router(2)

Comment: please take note that ICS was activated and that the PC's internet connection is working just fine with no problems at all.

thanks for trying to help! i appreciate it alot

Answer (score 0):

It depends on hardware of router.
The configuration when same wireless radio acts as a wireless client usually excludes ability to run access point on same radio.
Problem is almost completely solved in Win7 (not in Vista) https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/